# Почему echo выводит содержимое в том месте где функция объявлена, а не вызвана?

Tags: php, html

Функция вызывается в блоке над кнопкой заказать (см. скриншот)

```
                                <div class="date-block-radio"> 
                                ' . printdates($dates, $checkid) . '                  
                                </div>
```

И объявлена в начале страницы (см. скриншот). В связи с чем echo выводит содержимое не в месте вызова функции?

```
<div class="mains-block">
            <img src="back.jpg" class="back" alt="">
            <?
            $i = 1;
            $id = 0;
            $checkid = 1;
            $select = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `page_programs` ORDER BY `page_programs`.`program_id` ASC");
            $rowsCount = mysqli_num_rows($select);
            function printdates($datesparam, $checkidparam)
            {
                foreach ($datesparam as $rowdate) {
                    echo '
                    <label class="date" for="check' . $checkidparam . '" date="' . $rowdate['date'] . '">
                    ' . $rowdate['date'] . '
                    <input class="radio" type="radio" name="check" id="check' . $checkidparam . '" value="' . $rowdate['date'] . '" seatsNumber="' . $rowdate['number_of_seats'] . '">
                </label>
                ';
                    $checkidparam++;
                };
            };
```

Пробовал написать другую функцию с echo, она выводится там где вызвана.
Скриншот
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtTW0.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Сработало, заменив конкатенацию строки в echo на передачу параметров

```
<div class="date-block-radio"> 
' , printdates($dates, $checkid) , '                  
</div>
```